# Rectangle shape won't update left or top positions with canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, shapes

It won't change the position, the position is fixed at runtime even though i change the value 50 below:

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle myRectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();

mainGrid.Children.Add(myRectangle);

Canvas.SetLeft(myRectangle, 50);
Canvas.SetTop(myRectangle, 50);

myRectangle.Height = 100;
myRectangle.Width = 100;

myRectangle.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
```

Comment: is your rectangle contained within an actual canvas? it looks like it's in a grid object, so the Canvas.SetXXX won't do anything

Comment: Is this a `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` class instance? Or a `System.Drawing.Rectangle` structure? Give us a little more context. What is it that you expect to happen here?

Comment: @PeskyGnat is right, you can set the margin instead Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop -> myRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(50, 50, 0, 0);

Comment: It is a shape, and I added a canvas t the grid that I now appended it to and it's working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PeskyGnat: Please submit this as answer.

Comment: @Rubistro: Not my question, so...

Comment: @Rubistro: Yes, only the original poster can do that. This has been discussed at length on meta, it's probably better that way as well.

Answer (score 2):

here are the 2 solutions for your problem

1) with a canvas

```
var myRectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();

var mainCanvas = new Canvas();
mainGrid.Children.Add(mainCanvas);

mainCanvas.Children.Add(myRectangle);
Canvas.SetLeft(myRectangle, 50);
Canvas.SetTop(myRectangle, 50);

myRectangle.Height = 100;
myRectangle.Width = 100;
myRectangle.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
```

2) only with your grid

```
var myRectangle = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();

mainGrid.Children.Add(myRectangle);
myRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(50, 50, 0, 0);
myRectangle.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
myRectangle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;

myRectangle.Height = 100;
myRectangle.Width = 100;
myRectangle.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightSteelBlue;
```